Opening network folder in Windows file explorer using QGIS
Among the attributes of a layer, I have a "PERCORSO_CARTELLA_SP" field that points to a SharePoint network folder.
In QGIS 3.28.15, I can open the folder with Win10's file explorer using the "Attachment" Widget with the following options :

Unfortunately, QGIS reports the following warning whenever I open the attribute module or the table associated with the layer:

Is there a method or script in Python, preferably to put in the startup.py file, that removes the warning message?
I tried to adapt the code given on this page but without success:
https://docs.qgis.org/3.34/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/communicating.html#showing-progress
